# SOAP response data manipulation in azure apim

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Can you let me know how to change data in soap
Need to change n no. of properties and create new soap response in azure apim

I know i have to use set-body policy but how it is used for soap i dont know

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with liquid template:
[Using Liquid templates with set body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#using-liquid-templates-with-set-body)

There's also blog post: [Using Liquid Templates in Azure API Management](https://www.codit.eu/blog/using-liquid-templates-in-azure-api-management/)